# Contract.Requires for validations in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, code-contracts

I am developing MVC5 / Web API based application. In some articles I have read use `Contract.Requires` (part of the `System.Diagnostics.Contracts` namespace) for validating the incoming data.

Is this the correct way of validating the incoming data? Also I am not able to debug the `Contract.Requires` line as the debugger always bypasses this line. I am using Visual Studio 2013.

```
    public async Task<UserInfo> Put(
        [FromBody] UserInfo userInfo) {
        Contract.Requires(userInfo != null);
        ..............
     }
```

Can someone explain when to use `Contract.Requires` and where to avoid?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can use code contracts in your controllers but here are some downsides and reasons you may not need contracts.

- **Loss of error detail in API responses:** A code contract failure will be returned to the client as an HTTP 500 internal server error, likely without details, which is not helpful to clients of the API. This is because the contract failure causes an exception to be thrown. You may prefer to throw an `HttpResponseException` with your own details instead, or custom tailor an `HttpResponseMessage`. In that case (unless you roll your own global exception handling) code contracts may not make sense.
- **Contract.Requires may be redundant:** Consider how Web API may already be validating your parameters. For example, a missing parameter may result in an invalid route, so the request gets rejected and the method does not get called. Code contracts would be useless in this method.
- **Why do you need contracts?** Code contracts are great for catching contract failures at compile-time. But unless your API clients are also .NET projects, then you can't take advantage of that feature. So consider what else you might need contracts to do and if that justifies their usage.

Answer (score 3):

why contracts ?

you can use HttpResponseMessage in api methods :

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(UserInfo userInfo) {
     if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
     // your code
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    else
    {
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { msg = "invalid data" });
    }
    }
```

and or :

```
  [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Put(UserInfo userInfo) {
         if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
         // your code
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        else
        {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { msg = "invalid data" });
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

While Keith pointed out some perceived disadvantages of using Code Contracts in Web.Api I would like share some thoughts on where they might make sense or come in handy.

With Code Contracts you have a standard way on how to do input validation and verification of parameters (like assertions and even post-conditions).
This means you can code in the same way - whether you are inside an ApiController or in some other piece of code (such as an asynchronous worker thread).

Of course the general HTTP 500 message sent to the client is not helpful therefore we use Code Contracts in combination with a standard Web.Api exception handler (HttpStatusExceptionFilterAttribute). This exception handler will inspect the message and send a custom HTTP error code back to the client (optionally along with the condition that failed) plus it can log the full stack trace to your central application's log facility.

By utilising these two functionalities you clean and streamline your code while providing friendly and meaningful error information to the client and still preserving full error information for internal troubleshooting.

You can have a look at this article that explains it a little bit further: [Using CodeContracts with OData Controllers and Web.Api Exception Filters](http://d-fens.ch/2015/09/16/using-codecontracts-with-odata-controllers-and-web-api-exception-filters/)

hope this helps

Regards, Ronald